# How to make text JSON friendly? Java

Tags: java, json, maven

I have errors coming up with many things.

The biggest errors I have are with backslashes, greater than and less than operators, and quotes. I've done these operations on my text:

```
text.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"")
text.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")
```

None of these help. Is there anyone one method I can call to format a text into a JSON friendly text?

Comment: Use a JSON library to output JSON.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Gson is another Java JSON library that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as “JSON-friendly text”, since JSON can encode all Unicode strings.

To convert an arbitrary string into JSON format, use a JSON library like Jackson:

```
@Test
public void json() throws JsonProcessingException {
  TextNode textNode = new TextNode("quote\"quote");
  String jsonString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(textNode);
  assertEquals("\"quote\\\"quote\"", jsonString);
}
```